# fatal python error: py_initialize: unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: ubuntu, python, gnome-terminal

I have installed ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to launch terminal, it can't work. For this I have opened x-term and type gnome-terminal and I got the below error.

```
fatal python error: py_initialize: unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named "encoding"
```

Comment: what does `echo $PYTHONPATH` produce?

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH give empty result